# WCF Client for WCF REST service with Client Certificates - What am I missing?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, client-certificates

OK.  I've got my WCF REST service running just fine with Client Certificates via HttpWebRequest calls.  However, if I use this code it doesn't work:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;  
var factory = new WebChannelFactory<IMyContract>(new Uri(MyUrl));
var cc = factory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Find<ClientCredentials>();
cc.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,MySubjectName);
cc.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
cc.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
cc.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.TrustedStoreLocation = StoreLocation.LocalMachine;
cc.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, MyOtherSubjectName);
_svc = factory.CreateChannel();
var result1 = _svc.Post(GetMyPostObject());
```

I get the error:
`The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.`
But calling the *exact same service* on the *exact same url* with the *exact same client certificate* using `HttpWebRequest` works just fine.

I've also tried without all of the ServiceCertificate stuff but it made no difference
Can someone tell me what I've missed from my WCF code please?